# Overwriting SQLite database on a shared network folder

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 database on a shared folder. I want to overwrite the db file from a Java application. Though there is low read and write traffic on this file, I want to ensure that a) the overwrite doesn't corrupt the db file, and b) anyone who might be looking to access the db file will essentially see it locked until the overwrite is complete. My current plan looks something like this...

```
String query = "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION";
/* Execute this query*/
File sourceFile = new File(LocalPath);
File destFile = new File(DbPath);

InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int length;

while((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

inStream.close();
outStream.close();

/* Now release lock */

query = "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION";

/* Execute query */
```

So reading guidance from SQLite here http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html, it would seem this lock would exist in the journal and be updated after copy when I run the rollback transaction. In the meantime, if a client tries to access the Db while I'm copying, I imagine they would just not find the file and my SQLite driver assume the db doesn't exist. Right?

My question is... is it a moot point to place a lock on the db? Is there a better strategy or a way to make the db appear locked rather than missing? Also, am I running a huge risk in DB corruption that makes this unfeasible? One other thought I've had would be to lock the db file, write the new file to a different name, then rename after writing is complete, then release the lock... any thoughts on that?

Not sure if overwriting the DB file is a brilliant idea, but the only feasible thing I can think of for the resources I have at my disposal (running huge transactions on a db in a shared folder over the network is unacceptably slow. I am aware I run higher risk of corruption working with an SQLite db on a shared folder). I am writing updates locally and then letting the user elect to "commit" changes and initiate the db file copy.

In addition to answering my questions, any general advice on this case is welcome...

Comment: Do you know https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5 ?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5 Doesn't address overwriting an SQLite database nor strategies for access whilst overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) allows you to overwrite a database.

(I don't know if your Java wrapper exposes this API.)